# Argument is not aNaNunction, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm migrating from AngularJS 1.2.26 to 1.3.2 and receive an [Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=welcomeController&p1=not%20aNaNunction,%20got%20undefined)

Not the best error message to work out but it looks like it is saying that my controller is not defined? Can I no longer define controllers this way?

Error: error:areq

Bad Argument

Argument 'welcomeController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined

My index page is something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

var myApp = angular.module('kioskApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']).run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
});

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/welcome', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/welcome.php',
        controller  : 'welcomeController'
    });
});

function welcomeController($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {
    //stuff
}
```

My welcome page is something like:

```
<div ontouchmove="preventDrag(event)" ng-show="authenticated">
    <!-- some images -->
</div>
```

Comment: For reference, this error just means angular can't find the controller for one reason or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `controller: welcomeController` (without the quotes) to use it as a function.  Otherwise, do something like `myApp.controller('welcomeController', welcomeController)`.

You should also learn the [syntax for dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: What are the benefits for using module.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope, dep1, dep2) {}]); rather than function MyController($scope, dep1, dep2) {}; seems overly messy

Comment: @Craig first version makes your code minification proof.

Comment: Thank you, removing the quotes has worked. I didn't see anything in the migration docs, do you know if there is a separate migration doc for ng-route?

Comment: @Craig are you talking about for dependency injection?  It should work pretty much identically in all cases in Angular so there really shouldn't be anything different with how it works with ng-route

Comment: No sorry I meant for defining the controller using the $routeProvider but i guess you are saying it does work with quotes if I define the controller the angular way?