# ocLazyLoad and angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I want to add a `ocLazyLoad` in my mean-stack website. Here is the code:

```
    .state('kpi', {
        url:'/kpi',
        templateUrl: '/htmls/kpi.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('/javascripts/kpi-controller.js').then(function () {
                    console.log("done");
                }, function (e) {
                    console.log("error")
                })
            }]
        }}
```

Loading the `kpi` page returns

```
bootstrapped
kpi-controller inside
done
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=KpiCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

where the error is about `Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'KpiCtrl' is not a`.

`KpiCtrl` is defined in `kpi-controller.js`, and printing `kpi-controller inside` in the console shows the file has been indeed loaded. But why `KpiCtrl` is still not recognized?

One thing special about my code is, in the beginning of the program, I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myweb'])
    console.log("bootstrapped");
})
app = angular.module('myweb', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad']);
```

I did not understand `angular.bootstrap` well, but it seems that the new loaded `KpiCtrl` should be bootstrapped to be recognized. I tried to add `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myweb'])` inside `ocLazyLoad`, but it showed `App already bootstrapped with this element 'document'`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: 'NaNunction' is a common problem. It doesn't say that the controller is not recognized. It says that the argument is wrong. The question doesn't contain all necessary code. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834857/argument-is-not-ananunction-got-undefined

Comment: I see from a comment of the question you put: "For reference, this error just means angular can't find the controller for one reason or another. – Planky"

Comment: Comments aren't always correct. This one certainly isn't. The error could appear due to the fault of ocLazyLoad, yet the cause isn't known.